# fitsSystemWindows and extra padding on kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, translucentdecor

I have a ListView in an activity with an actionbar like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:context=".LauncherActivity"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvcalendar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:divider="#00ffffff"

            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbarstyle"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity theme have:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Under Kitkat devices, the behaviour is what I want: the items have 10dp padding at the bottom and at the top. On kitkat devices the paddingTop and paddingBottom seem to have no efect as the ListView's item do not have the 10dp padding at the top and bottom.

I think the problem is somewhere in `android:fitsSystemWindows` as this attribute seem to set the necessary padding to the view because of translucent decor and make the `android:padding*` attributes being ignored.

**My question**: is there anyway so I can have the `android:fitsSystemWindows` set to `true` and still add extra padding on the view?

Comment: please check the answer as Accepted ! , what's Wrong ?

Comment: The behaviour I want is not what @Spirit said.

Comment: did you find solution already? got the same problem

Comment: No. I actually forgot this question here. I'm the owner of this question and I'm not allowed to down vote the solutions that I tested that don't work? This stackoverflow is just useless like that. Anyway, other people just up voted in something that is not the solution. Still, useless place to share questions and answers.

Answer (score 14):

You should add this attribute to parent view :

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".LauncherActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Comment: If add this to the parent activity, the listview won't fill the navigation bar.
I still want to have the listview behind the translucent navigation bar but the I want to have the extra padding plus the fitsSystemWindows' padding. It may be not possible, I don't know. If you need more info or screenshoots just say. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own class that extends ListView and override [`fitSystemWindows()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#fitSystemWindows%28android.graphics.Rect%29) in that class, in order to add the insets to the existing padding (the default implementation replaces any padding with the insets). Then you don't need to specify the `android:fitsSystemWindows` attribute in the layout XML because your new implementation will always be called.

Comment: It seems that's what I need. I'll try as soon as possible and I'll tell here the results and solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. If you set android:fitsSystemWindows as true, it overwrites padding of that view.

You can achieve the behavior you want by having two nested views, where the parent view has android:fitsSystemWindows as true and other contains the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Move your             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
to your parent ListView

Answer (score -1):

When you use:

```
fitsSystemWindows=true
```

To a layout, padding will be reset to insets. You can use the [FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/FitsSystemWindowsFrameLayout) to solve this default behavior.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).